# Get parent site calendar list data from SharePoint app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, ajax, angularjs, cross-domain

I am trying to get parent site calendar list data from SharePoint app page.

I have used one function for getting data. THe function name is `GetParentSiteListData()`. I can call this function when loading `mainController` in `Angularjs`s.

Code is,

```
function GetParentSiteListData() {
    var getParentListurl = "https://sharepointsite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitename" + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('projectCalendar')/items?$select = Id, Title";
    return $.ajax({
        url: getParentListurl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("GetParentSiteListData ", data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("GetParentSiteListData Error ", JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
}
```

After loading `GetParentSiteListData()` function, I am getting error message like,

```
"GetParentSiteListData Error  
{
"readyState":4,
"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-2147024891,
 System.UnauthorizedAccessException\",
\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",
\"value\":\"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.\"}}}",
"status":403,
"statusText":"Forbidden"
}"
```

What can I do to get parent site list items to display in SharePoint app page?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article. It explains both setting the correct permissions for your app for access parent web or site and also how to make the call using REST api: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179927.aspx